# Reading multiple CSVs into different arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, numpy

Update. Here is my code. I am importing 400 csv files into 1 list. Each csv file is 200 rows and 5 columns. My end goal is to sum the values from the 4th column of each row or each csv file. The below code imports all the csv files. However, I am struggling to isolate 4th column of data from each csv file from the large list.

```
for i in range (1, 5, 1):

data = list()
for i in range(1,400,1):
    datafile = 'particle_path_%d' % i
    data.append(np.genfromtxt(datafile, delimiter = "", skip_header=2))
print datafile
```

I want to read 100 csv files into 100 different arrays in python. For example:

array1 will have csv1
array2 will have csv2 etc etc.

Whats the best way of doing this? I am appending to a list right now but I have one big list which is proving difficult to split into smaller lists. My ultimate goal is to be able to perform different operations of each array (add, subtract numbers etc)

Comment: Can you **edit** the question with your current relevant `code` please?

Comment: Can you read the files ok with `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt`? You'll have to be more specific about you need to do with the list(s) of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more detail on what needs to be done? If you are simply trying to read line by line in the csv files and make that the array then this should work:

I would create a 2 dimensional array for this, something like:

```
csv_array_container = []
for csv_file in csv_files:
    csv_lines = csv_file.readlines()
    csv_array_container.append(csv_lines)
#Now close your file handlers
```

Assuming that csv_files is a list of open file_handlers for the csv files. Something more appropriate would likely open the files in the loop and close them after use rather than open 100, gather data, and close 100 due to limits on file handlers.

If you would like more detail on this, please give us more info on what you are exactly trying to do with examples. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use a 3D array, with the container holding a list of 2D arrays where they are essential the csv loaded in a matrix like format. This will allow you to index the headers and data below. However more appropriate solutions may be possible depending on what you are trying to accomplish, check out the csv library for python :)

Comment: `numpy`, see the tag, has `csv` loaders.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of 100 arrays.  What can you tell us about their shapes?

If they all have the same shape you could use

```
arr = np.stack(data)
```

I expect `arr.shape` will be (100,200,5)

```
fthcol = arr[:,:,3]   # 4th column
```

If they aren't all the same, then a simple list comprehension will work

```
fthcol = [a[:,3] for a in data]
```

Again, depending on the shapes you could `np.stack(fthcol)` (choose your axis).

Don't be afraid to iterate over the elements of the `data` list.  With 100 items the cost won't be prohibitive.

Comment: Hi hpaulj, stack works well. All my arrays are of the same shape. To finish it off I want to slice the stacked array ever nth row. For example, array1 will have rows 0-10, array2 will have rows 11-21 etc etc. I see there is a slice function, but I am unsure as to how to iterate through the array name with an increasing value (array1, array2 etc)                      each time